# Trying replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

Trying to replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04, but HP 6000 Pro keeps wanting to boot and repair in Windows 8 despite having chosen dedicate it to Ubuntu during the installation.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This little tool should solve your issue: [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home)

You can use it either from your Ubuntu disc, or via a dedicated rescue disc.

[image]